# Why is my iPhone app listed as iPad compatible?

Tags: iphone, ipad

In xcode my targeted device family was iPhone. After I submitted my app Apple has it listed in iTunes as iPhone, iPod touch and iPad compatible. why would they list it as ipad compatible when the targeted device is iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because iPhone apps can run on the iPad.

You don't have to write a specific iPad version to get iPad compatibility because of this, which is nice. It does mean people might be running your app on iPad in pixel-doubled mode, which will make it look pixellated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because all iPhone/iPod Touch apps are required to at least operate in compatibility mode on the iPad.